# PrimeNG DataTable doesn't allow Group and Sortable to exist together

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG's DataTable (http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable).  I defined one of the columns to be sortable ().  That worked great until I wanted to have grouped headers using the group approach.

```
this.headerRows = [
    {
        columns: [
            {header: 'Station Data', colspan: 3}
        ]
    },
    {
        columns: [
            {header: 'ID'},
            {header: 'Name'},
            {header: 'Basin'}           
        ]
    }
];



     <p-dataTable [value]="stationsArray" [headerRows]="headerRows" [globalFilter]="gb" [rows]="3" [paginator]="true" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[3,5,7]" scrollWidth="100%" >  
            <!-- ID -->
            <p-column field="id" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
            <p-column field="name" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
     </p-dataTable>
```

At that point, the sortable column stopped showing the sort indicator.  Can these not be used together? [image of grouped headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLapL.png)

Comment: added a question on the forum : http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=47725&sid=d9aed09b5dd0495fd99a3a4c1d7e750c